# @font-face doesn't load font

Tags: css, font-face

@font-face doesn't load my font, in Firefox, safari, Dolphin mobile. 
Stylesheet looks like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'eveleth_regularbold';
    src: url('/fonts/evelethbold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/evelethbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/evelethbold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/evelethbold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/evelethbold-webfont.svg#eveleth_regularbold') format('svg');
}       
.titel{
color: #f1e176;
font-family: 'eveleth_regularbold';
}
```

I tried absolute urls before, didn't work either.

Comment: Can you share the live link or upload it on jsfiddle or Codepen?

Comment: Is `.titel` a mistake?

Comment: Hey, but you have to attributes named `src`!

Comment: Is it opening one of the font files in any browser?

Comment: Your code [seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/geuf0b56/3/). Please include enough code in the question (possibly backed by a fiddle) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: wow, that was quick..

Comment: here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/powtyknn/

Comment: when pasting teh adress to the browser, it finds it, could download the font